# Rubymotion: More generic way to set navigationBar properties

Tags: ios, ruby, rubymotion

Is there a more generic way to set the navigationBar properties? I would like to set the translucent to false and an image as a title. What is strange for me is that I can set the  tintColor and barTintColor in `app_delegate.rb` but not the other properties. It is a little weird to run this code in all my screens.

I am using the latest Rubymotion and I am using the promotion gem to build my screens.

```
class AppDelegate < ProMotion::Delegate
  include PM::Styling

  def on_load(app, options)
    set_appearance_defaults
  end

  def set_appearance_defaults
    UINavigationBar.appearance.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor
    UINavigationBar.appearance.barTintColor = hex_color("3B4044")
  end

end

class LoginScreen < PM::Screen

  def on_init
    self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView.alloc.initWithImage(UIImage.imageNamed("logos/navigation_bar_logo.png"))
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = false
  end

end
```

Comment: You can always subclass UINavigationController if you're going to have the same nav bar all through your app or really, more than once.

Comment: Another thing though is (this is UX stuff sorry) it's not recommended to place a logo in the nav bar.

Comment: Or subclass PM::Screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added some comments above, but here's an actual answer you can try out for yourself that's pretty flexible.

```
# app/mk_screen.rb
class MKScreen < PM::Screen
  def useLogoNavbar
    self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView.alloc.initWithImage(UIImage.imageNamed("logos/navigation_bar_logo.png"))
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = false
  end
end

# app/login_screen.rb
class LoginScreen < MKScreen
  useLogoNavbar
end
```

Now you still have to call a method, but it at least gives you an option of whether to use it or not. It also means you can use MKScreen to place little common code in for your view controllers.